# Why doesn't extracting the analytic signal work for all kinds of signals?

Tags: complex-analysis, signal-processing

So one technique in signal processing and comm. technology is to extract the analytic signal of a real-valued signal. And particularly they often extract the magnitude of the analytic signal in order to get the *envelope* of the signal.

However, several sources claim that this method works well only for band-limited signals. Why is this?

Given that the concept of analytic function should apply to all signals, then why does it work only for band-limited signals?

Ref.

http://es.mathworks.com/examples/signal/mw/signal-ex19772739-envelope-extraction-using-the-analytic-signal

Answer (score 1):

A function that is not band limited may not be smooth enough to be possible to make complex analytic. The Hilbert transform tries to find the imaginary part of a function so that the Cauchy Riemann equations are fulfilled - in other words : "extend" it to become complex analytic. But not all real valued functions are so nicely behaving so that is possible to do.

Comment: Aha, so band-limited here is synonymous to "being continuous in an interval/subset", but not necessarily on the entire domain?

Comment: @mavavilj : I suspect band limited to mean in math language to have a compactly supported Fourier transform. "Band"-limited is engineering language and refers to the frequency-bands of the Fourier transform.